How can I show in a formal way this solution of Bezdek-Connelly Theorem?
Question
Show that for $n=4$, the Bezdek-Connelly theorem is tight: there exists 4 unit circles in the plane such that every two circles intersect at exactly two points, and there are exactly 4 intersections.
Note
Bezdek-Connelly theorem: Let $\mathcal{C}$ be a family of $n$ unit circles in the plane such that each circle has at least a common point with another and no two are tangent, then the number of intersection points is at least $n$.
Attempt
I managed to come up with a diagram to show this configuration exists, but I don’t know how to make this formal. Your help would be appreciated.

For readers who don't know this theorem, see here.

@JeanMarie I think I have figured it out. Following the proof of theorem 1 in the link you provided, we may give a weight of 1 unit to each point of intersection. Then, we will distribute the weight of each point between the circles that pass through that point. In the end, we see that each circle has the same number of weight, which is 1.

Give weight 1 to every intersection point. Then equally distribute the weight of each intersection point among the circles passing through it. Notice that we have three circles passing through each point. This means for each point, the circles passing through it will have a weight of $\frac{1}{3}$ each. In the end, each circle will have a total weight of 1.
